# Jmeter - Append MyValues to Dashboard Report

Tags: charts, jmeter, dashboard

I have a question regarding Jmeter Dashboard Report.

I want to append a value into a chart. I'm using `sample_variables` and `display custom graphs`, but I can't find a way to display my custom graphs into build-in graphs like: 'Response Times Over Time'.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Yosi, could you please add some more details on what product you use and what you've tried. From the description above it's hard to tell how we can help you.

Comment: Sure
Im working on Jmeter with a simple thread which simulates 50 users with a loop. Each response include value which i extracted and save. The value is the time the server send me. 
Now i runing dashboard report include sample_variables which i can see in my custom graph. I wnat to add my graph to build-in graph. Add my value to existing chart. Im runing the Jmeter script haedless